# I load data from my DB that crashes my app, error: "Path contains empy part"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                theName = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
    }
```

I get the value of "theName" that is a string in my log but it crashes when I try to bind it to my label. The error says: "Path contains empy part".

The info in the DB that i am trying to load has text that contains "" marks, dots, and :, ¨and åäö ó for example. I assume that is the issue.

I tried to experiment with something like this after I recieved the data but without any results:

```
  new StringContent (theName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

This is how i load the data from my DB:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("localhost");

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        return jsonResult;

    }
```

Comment: If the web service is running on your computer (not phone) you should use the computer name instead of localhost

Comment: the web service is amazon and i get the http via an IP. could it be an issue?